# case expression inside this left join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, case

so I have this left join

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT d.country FROM db.patient_info d
           WHERE  d.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT st.category FROM db.surgery_types st, db.surgery_record sr
               WHERE sr.id = st.surgery_record_id AND sr.surgery_type_id = m.id)
           ORDER BY d.priority, d.country
           LIMIT 1
           
         ) c ON TRUE
```

the issue is that sometimes d.country comes back null. How can I add a case statement in the left join so that when d.country IS NULL then 'USA'?

My results look like this

| Patient Name | Surgery Type |
| --- | --- |
| Dave | USA |
| Richard | EU |
| Ben | EU |
| Sally | JP |
| Bob | null |
| Dicky | null |

I want to modify the left join so that it looks more like this

| Patient Name | Surgery Type |
| --- | --- |
| Dave | USA |
| Richard | EU |
| Ben | EU |
| Sally | JP |
| Bob | USA |
| Dicky | USA |

Thoughts?

Comment: A [mcve] isd a great start when asking for SQL assistance. (We don't know what you have, or what you want.=

Comment: Yes, simply use `COALESCE()` as @Schwern suggested. But your query looks overcomplicated, and I'm not sure you really get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`coalesce`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) which returns the first non-null value.

```
-- I have no idea if this lateral join is valid.
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT coalesce(d.country, 'USA')
  FROM db.patient_info d
  WHERE  d.id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT st.category
    FROM db.surgery_types st, db.surgery_record sr
    WHERE sr.id = st.surgery_record_id AND sr.surgery_type_id = m.id
  )
  ORDER BY d.priority, d.country
  LIMIT 1         
) c ON TRUE
```

Though the order by will still use null so it might not sort properly. You might want to split this into a CTE.

```
-- Again, no idea if the lateral join is valid,
-- just showing a technique.
with countries as(
  SELECT coalesce(d.country, 'USA') as country
  FROM db.patient_info d
  WHERE  d.id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT st.category
    FROM db.surgery_types st
    JOIN db.surgery_record sr ON sr.id = st.surgery_record_id
    -- Don't know what m is
    WHERE sr.surgery_type_id = m.id
  )
)
with first_country as (
  select country
  from countries
  order by priority, country
  limit 1
)
select
...
LEFT JOIN LATERAL countries on true
```

Finally, it might be simpler and faster to update the table to set all null countries to `USA`, and then make the column `not null`.

Comment: LATERAL without its derived table? Does Postgresql accept that syntax?

Comment: using coalesce here returns d.country does not exist up in my select statement.

Comment: @jarlh No idea, there's too little information in this fragment.

Comment: @icebox That indicates `db.patient_info` does not have a `country` column. I'm not sure how your query ever worked. I can't help with debugging from just your query fragment, only to say that `coalesce` does what you want: return a default value if it's null.

Comment: @Schwern so the column exists, I wonder if it has to do with aliases, I'm using this in my Select statement 
`SELECT d.country country_name`

Comment: @Schwern and isn't coalesce being called before the actual where statement is triggered?

Comment: @icebox `coalesce` is called on the results of the query. I can't help debug your query with incomplete information. If you can provide a schema, working query, sample data, and expected results you will get better help.

Answer (score 0):

Not looking into your business logic and whether a lateral join is needed at all or a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) in the select list of expressions would be enough, here is my suggestion.

```sql
CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
(
 select coalesce
 (
   ( /* your lateral subquery in the brackets here */),
   'USA'
 ) as country
) as c
```

You do not need left join anymore. Please note that this will only work if the subquery is scalar.